# Changing Bootstrap 4 Dropdown Button Colors

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to change the buttons' colors, but I only managed to change the colors when hovered so far.

Here is my HTML and this is my CSS when it changes color by hovering::

```css
.nav > li > a:focus, .nav > li > a:hover {
       background-color: #00AEFE;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



 
 
 <nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Food, LLC</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapsable-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Chicken</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Beef</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sushi</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You can use the browsers element inspector to see what CSS is applied to the elements, this will tell you what elements and styles you need to override.

Comment: If you use SCSS you can amend the bootstrap color variables: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#color. Alternatively you can amend the CSS variables directly: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#available-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the general color, delete the :focus and the :hover (only active when focused or hovered)

```
.nav > li > a{
   background-color: #00AEFE;
}
```

Even better:

```
.navbar-toggle {
     background-color: #00AEFE;
}
```

Note: This only changes the style of the element containing "navbar-toggle" in class